# Include two versions of Jar

Tags: build, gradle

I am new to gradle. 
I have two versions of Pig UDF (written in Java) com.x.test-udf:test-udf:0.0.3 & com.x.test-udf:test-udf:0.0.4 
Is it possible in gradle to define dependency on both of them and have both jars included in the final build? How will the sample dependency declaration look like?

Thanks
Abhijit

Comment: It is possible but the versions may be conflicting.

Comment: do you happen to have a sample that you can share? From Pig script it is possible to refer to a specific jar using REGISTER command. So there may be a way to resolve the conflict.